# Could not see site collection info from view all site collection

Tags: 2010

We had to do database move from our non prod to prod env. Both env are in the same domain. But site collection admin credentials are different.

We carried out mountdatabase PS command with assignnewdatabaseID parameter. It took a long while, but we can now see the contentdb in the contentdb list at Central Admin. We can open and check the details of the content db. Site collection number is 1 for this contentdb (e.g. contentdbA).

When we go to View All Site Collection at the Central Admin, we can see the site collection for the contentdbA (e.g. SiteCollA). But when we clicked on the SiteCollA, the info on the site collection is not showing. Any idea why this happened?

Answer (score 2):

This thing happen with me too, two things to try

- detach the content database and reattach it.sometime information not properly synced.
- you can also reset IIS on server.

Comment: Ms. Sarwar, our mistake. our spfarmadmin was not added as primary site collection administrator. once added, our issue is resolved. we're still checking though for any other complication. and no, we did not do iisreset after the mountdb as this is prod env. will take note of this for future similar activity.

Comment: Glad u fix the issue...but one thing IIS reset does not required after every mount....it is only if there is some issue

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved. must make sure farm admin added as primary site collection administrator. to check if there's issue with the mountdb step, check at PS for site collection info for the contentdb or contentdb info for the site collection